# C#: PATH Environment Variable

Tags: c#, path, environment

I have a problem, I've written a code to install a batch file to the registry and to the PATH under Advanced Settings, so it can be used under the right click menu.

It works until I click on this right click item. After that it just shows a window for a millisecond (I don't know which one) and nothings happens.

The batch file is working (I tested it). I also checked the registry entry (it is 100% correct, like it should be when I do it manually). So the only thing is left is the PATH under Advanced System Settings...

First the code:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "PATH", 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + 
        Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + "FastAndDelete\\",
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);**

RegistryKey reg = Registry
    .ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Directory", true)
    .OpenSubKey("shell", true);
reg.CreateSubKey("FastAndDelete");
reg.OpenSubKey("FastAndDelete", true)
    .CreateSubKey("command")
    .SetValue("", "cmd /c " + '“' + "cd %1 && fastdel.bat" + '”');
reg.Close();
```

I also tried

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "PATH", 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + 
        Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + 
        "FastAndDelete\\;", 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

and

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "PATH", 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + 
        Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + 
        "FastAndDelete\\fastdel.bat", 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

and

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    "PATH", 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + 
        Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory) + 
        "FastAndDelete\\fastdel.bat;", 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

I also tried it without the ";" at the beginning, but nothing helps.

Do someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? If it's a bat file what you are running, it would show a command window while it's running and after that it would close,so if the execution is fast, you'll see the efect you are describing

Comment: Out of interest why a batch file and not do the delete in c#?

Comment: Those smart quote characters you're putting in the registry look suspicious "cmd /c " + '“' + ... + '”'.  Try replacing them with dumb quotes "cmd /c " + '"' + ... + '"'

Comment: yeah you where right it was //  "cmd /c " + '“' + ... + '”'. Try replacing them with dumb quotes "cmd /c " + '"' + ... + '"' // . I copied this from the website and just added the nessecary code so it whould print. So this was wrong from the website... and I look at this code for hours and think what I have done wrong -.- thank you very much

Comment: @Joe Between how can I upvote your comment?

Comment: @Pikoh I recordet the screen and the command promt what's popping up was a failure (it didn't reach the right file). Like Joe found out: I overviewed the incorrect " signs

Comment: @BugFinder I searched for a fast way to delete large files. The best answer I could get was via command promp. And on that site, they made this .bat file and registered it manually, but I didn't want to do that again and again on ever PC I have or will have (and some of my friends wanted this way of deleting too, but don't know how they can do it). So I made this little "Installer".

Comment: @AlucardOlbaid Fair enough - my dos fu is probably stronger than yours, but you can do one in c# that would run just as quick.. then you wouldnt have chance of wrong paths, missing whatevers..

Comment: @AlucardOlbaid - as an aside, replacing "cmd /c" (execute command and exit) by "cmd /k" (exit command and stay active) is often a useful way of seeing what's wrong with a command without having it exit and close the command window before you've had time to see the error.

Comment: @Joe thank you, I will keep that in mind for the future.